# Python Webbrowser module not giving the desired output

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

Hey guys I'am testing a python module named 'webbrowser' but its not giving any responses when I tries to open youtube. Please solve this problem.
This is the code.

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("www.youtube.com")
```

And I'm not getting any error also.
On Printing it is showing :

```
True
```

When I tried this code :

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get("google-chrome"),open("https://www.youtube.com")
```

It gives this error:

```
webbrowser.get("google-chrome"),open("https://www.youtube.com")  
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\webbrowser.py", line 65, in get
raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

Answer (score 1):

Please locate your browser path and then register it through [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register), Then run the webbrowser.

```
import webbrowser    
urL='https://www.google.com'
chrome_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path), 1)
webbrowser.get('chrome').open(urL)
```

Comment: what do You think printing it out will give?

Comment: print it shows if the command runs properly or not.

Comment: I printed, well for me it shows True, and I guess for OP it could show False but that doesn't help much does it, although sure do that to check if anything happens

Comment: Its giving True here but not working ! Is there any solution ? or How can I put the default browser path in system path.

Comment: If you have firefox test this code: `webbrowser.get("firefox").open("https://www.youtube.com")
`
If you have google chrome replace `firefox` with `google-chrome`  and see the result.

Comment: @AliIrani I tried your code and its giving an error that It is not able to locate the browser.                                                                                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  , line 3, in <module>
    webbrowser.get("google-chrome"),open("https://www.youtube.com")  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\webbrowser.py", line 65, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

Comment: @AliIrani  I also tried to this code with chrome path but its giving the same error.

Comment: Please try with `get('chrome')` and see that works? If not add chrome pass to your os path and check again with `chrome` or `google-chrome`

Comment: @AliIrani Please can you explain how to add chrome to os path of Windows 10.

Comment: This link seems useful. https://support.leapwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001192311-Could-not-open-Chrome-please-check-that-it-is-properly-installed-on-your-computer

Comment: @AliIrani Bro I have added the chrome to os path but its not giving any output.  please tell any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try both `chrome` & `google-chrome`?

Comment: @AliIrani   Yes I have tried both chrome & google-chrome but its giving the same error that can't find the runnable browser. Can Reinstalling the Python 3.9 solve this Problem.

Comment: I don't think reinstalling python helps. I edited my solution to register the browser in your code. Please try it.

Comment: @AliIrani I have tried your code its giving this error :          webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path), 1)
TypeError: register() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.          Please this Problem

Comment: I figure out maybe our problem is somewhere else. Please try this: `webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("http://google.com")` or change that path with your chrome path. Please change all `\\` to one `/` similar to my code

Comment: @AliIrani I have tried but its not giving any output please tell other solution. Or is there any other method to search through web browser.